# Пытаюсь на блоггере запаролить отдельные посты, но скрипт блокирует главную

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь на блоггере запаролить отдельные посты, но проблема в том, что скрипт блокирует главную страницу. Вот скрипт:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
pass = prompt('Enter Password, please:');
if (pass=='!!!0!!!') {
    alert('!!!1!!!')
} else {
    alert('!!!2!!!'), top.location.href="!!!3!!!"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ваш скрипт работает в рамках одной страницы. js скрипт работает на той странице, где он выполняется и если я правильно понял вашу задумку, то вы не сделаете желаемое на клиентском js. Нужно написать логику с проверкой на стороне бэкэнда. Более того - ваш пароль в случае с текущим скриптом хранится в открытом виде и любой желающий сможет посмотреть его открыв скрипт.

Comment: да мне нужно запоролить именно определенные посты,но еслиоткрываю главную,вместо нее открывается запароленная страница,их будет не мало и просто ждать когда они уйдут назад тоже бесмысленно.и еще не забывайте это блоггер!!!

Comment: вот больной https://zagovoryprivoroty.blogspot.com/,моя задача некоторые книги спрятать паролем,устала шаманить ничего не получается